# Changing series colors by series name in a Chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-charts

I'm having hard time with a line chart that contains multiple series (over 170 at the moment). I would like to color each series based on few letters that appear on the series names - the series names may contain other info than these letters only.

Let's say I'd like to color each series that contain letters ABC (in this particular order) with red, series containing DEF with black and series containing GHI with blue.

I know some basics of programming (mainly PHP and Python), but I'm not very familiar with VBA. With the following line of code, I can change colors of series from 1 to 10. How could I express the for-loop such way, that it would process only series that contain certain words of letters in their series names?

```
Dim j As Long
     With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        For j = 1 To 10
            With .SeriesCollection(j)
                .MarkerStyle = 2
                .MarkerSize = 7
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            End With
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to resolve this by myself. I used If-condition inside For-loop, and used InStr() function to check if series name (ser.Name) contains the wanted letter. I hope this helps someone else having the same problem. Please see below.

```
Dim ser As Series
 
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        For Each ser In .SeriesCollection
            With ser
                If InStr(ser.Name, "ABC") Then
                    .MarkerStyle = 2
                    .MarkerSize = 7
                    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                End If
            End With
        Next ser
    End With
End Sub
```